# Flex 4 UIMovieClip Modify the Width of a Child DisplayObject

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I have a collection of UIMovieClip components which reside in an s:HGroup tag.  In ActionScript code I am modifying the width of a child clip in one of the UIMovieClips but these changes are not reflected by the s:HGroup.

```
<s:HGroup id="_buttonGroup">
    <uiassets:NavigationTabButtonSWC id="_lobby" />
    <uiassets:NavigationTabButtonSWC id="_achievements" />
</s:HGroup>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function init() : void
        {
            // The HGroup does not pickup this change and so my buttons
            // are no longer evenly spaced out and overlap!
            _lobby.getChildByName("background").width += 200;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of getChildByName("background")?

Comment: We ended up porting this code to use Pure AS3 in the end - Flex was bogging things down too much! :)

Comment: +1 for an unorthodox solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few reasons for this.  Just changing one child's width doesn't mean it'll change the whole UIMovieClip's width, so you should check that first.

Second, Flex has a very specific way of doing things (called the component lifecycle), which the UIMovieClip doesn't implement so you can't manage the width yourself in the 'measure' function.  I'm guessing that you just have other children in your movieclip that doesn't let you resize it all.  Try changing the width of the MovieClip itself and it should work.  If it doesn't, then there's another problem.